# How to prevent displaying the total sum of A + B if columns A + B are empty

Tags: numbers

I have inserted a running total formula in my numbers sheet.
It sums the total of Column H, which works fine.
However when cells in columns H are empty it will display the last sum, which I do not want.

How can I prevent displaying the last sum when Column A and B are empty?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can extend the formula to check whether the value in the column to the left is empty or not:

```
=if(j3>0;sum(h$2:h3);"")
```

Comment: Works like a charm thnks